# Unit testing in a legacy ASP.NET application to mock HttpContext

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, httpcontext

I have a method:

```
public DataSet someMethod()
{
    List a = someObj.getList(name, integerId);
}
```

Now the integerId is obtained through the `HttpContext.Current.Session` variable.
I have written a unit test for the method. But since, the test runs outside of the web process, `HttpContext.Current.Session` returns null and the test fails.

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Mocking HttpContext is difficult in classic ASP.NET.  I suggest you wrap your references to HttpContext.Session in your own mockable class.

Comment: Data acess layer should not depends on HttpContext object.

Comment: Yes, ideally that should be the case. However, in order to follow that, a large amount of code in my project would have to be re factored.

Answer (score 1):

First you'll have to initialize [`HttpContext.Current`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33343616/4332059):

```
HttpContext.Current = new HttpContext(new HttpRequest("", "http://blabla.com", "") {},
                                      new HttpResponse(new StringWriter()));
```

Then you'll have to set the session:(Necroskillz has explained the way to do this in [his blog](http://www.necronet.org/archive/2010/07/28/unit-testing-code-that-uses-httpcontext-current-session.aspx/))

```
public static void SetFakeSession(this HttpContext httpContext)
{
    var sessionContainer = new HttpSessionStateContainer("id", 
                                             new SessionStateItemCollection(),
                                             new HttpStaticObjectsCollection(), 10, true,
                                             HttpCookieMode.AutoDetect,
                                             SessionStateMode.InProc, false);

    httpContext.Items["AspSession"] = typeof(HttpSessionState).GetConstructor(
                                             BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance,
                                             null, CallingConventions.Standard,
                                             new[] { typeof(HttpSessionStateContainer) },
                                             null)
                                        .Invoke(new object[] { sessionContainer });
}
```

The following snippet shows how it works:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    HttpContext.Current = new HttpContext(new HttpRequest("", "http://blabla.com", "") {},
                                          new HttpResponse(new StringWriter()));

    HttpContext.Current.SetFakeSession();

    HttpContext.Current.Session["foo"] = 1;

    Assert.AreEqual(1, HttpContext.Current.Session["foo"]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess the lazy answer to this question would be: learn to use [dependency injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130794/what-is-dependency-injection), but I'll go ahead and provide some pointers.

It is unlikely the class needs *everything* in HttpContext. You don't specify how you compute your `integerId`, but let's say it's a hash of the current `SessionState`'s `SessionId`. All your class actually need is *some way to get that particular `SessionId`*; that doesn't need to be an entire `HttpContext`.

```
interface ICurrentSessionIdProvider
{
     string SessionId { get; }
}
```

And now your class has:

```
// Pull this from a constructor parameter so you can provide any implementation you want
private readonly ICurrentSessionIdProvider _sessionIdProvider;

public DataSet someMethod()
{
     int integerId = _sessionIdProvider.SessionId.GetHashCode();
     List a = someObj.getList(name, integerId);
}
```

Now in your unit test it becomes trivial to mock this dependency. Tools like Moq and AutoFixture will even do it for you and now your life is easy and happy etc.

Of course in the real application you want to use an implementation based on  HttpContext:

```
class HttpContextCurrentSessionIdProvider : ICurrentSessionIdProvider   
{
     // Pull this from a constructor parameter or however you see fit.
     private readonly HttpContext _httpContext;

     public SessionId => _httpContext.Current.Session.SessionId;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to inject a fake `HttpContext` for your test somehow - ideally as `HttpContextBase`, which is a mockable but otherwise identical API.

You can wrap `HttpContext` in an `HttpContextWrapper` to get an `HttpContextBase`.

Have a read up on the various techniques for Inversion of Control, and find one that works for you.